# Change text in div when typing in form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this code, that live-update text in a div when user type in a text area.
I'm not sure how to edit it, so i can re-use it for several matching div/input.

Is it possible to use some kind of wildcard?

My working code:

```
<textarea id="input-address" name="address" rows="5" class="form-control">{{ Auth::user()->address }}</textarea>
<div id="output-address">{{ Auth::user()->address }}</div>

$(function() {
    $source=$("#input-address");
    $output=$("#output-address");
    $source.keyup(function() {
       $output.text($source.val());
    });
});
```

I was thinking about something like this, but not sure how to handle it:

```
<input type="text" id="input-first_name" name="first_name" class="form-control" value="{{ Auth::user()->first_name }}" required>    
<textarea id="input-address" name="address" rows="5" class="form-control">{{ Auth::user()->address }}</textarea>

<div id="output-first_name">{{ Auth::user()->first_name}}</div>
<div id="output-address">{{ Auth::user()->address }}</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $source=$("#input-[name-match]");
        $output=$("#output-[name-match]");
        $source.keyup(function() {
           $output.text($source.val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could use it as you described above, but you should attach a common dynamic `input` event like :

```
$(function() {
    //Attach 'input' event to all elements that have an 'id' start with 'input-'
    $('[id^="input-"]').on('input', function(){
        var source_name = $(this).attr('name');

        //Change the element that have 'id' equal to 'output-source_name'
        $('#output-'+source_name).text( $(this).val() );
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.input').on('input', function(){
    var source_name = $(this).attr('name');

    $('#output-'+source_name).text( $(this).val() );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control input" value="first_name from controller" required>    
<br>
<textarea name="address" rows="5" class="form-control input">address  from controller</textarea>

<div id="output-first_name">first_name from controller</div>
<div id="output-address">address  from controller</div>
```

Comment: Okay, let me know if this is correct. It fetch all "id=input-" and grab the value of attribute name="?" and uses that to find the matching div with the same id? so the id of the input fields are just used to let the function know, that is has to grab the name attribute and use that, to find a matching div. It's this part that confuses me a little: $(this).attr('name')

Comment: The `id`'s of the fields, Yes that true.. you could instead just use a class `input` in your fields... `$(this).attr('name')` will get the name of the current edited field to target the related `div` that have the id `output-THE NAME OF THE CURRENT EDITED FIELD`.

Comment: Check my updated snippet using a common class `input` on fields instead of id's.

Answer (score 2):

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(":text").keyup(function () {
      $("p").text($(":text").val());
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  User Name: <br>
  <input type="text" >
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<br>
<p>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help to solve your problem.

```
$('#input-address').keyup(function() {

    var address= $('#input-address').val();        

    $('#output-address').html(address);
    });
```